# SQLite+FMDB: parallel querying of multiple databases

Tags: sqlite, parallel-processing, fmdb

This is research question.

Say I have N SQLite databases, each database in its own file.
They have exactly the same schema but different data sets.
I want to write **single application** that can query in **parallel** manner each database and then to do something with received data.

So I want to know whether 1) SQLite allows to open and operate **multiple independent** database connections concurrently; 2) FMDB supports such operation mode.

Answer (score -2):

This is very tricky question and by this we can know about capability of `FMDB` with SQLite database.

In **FMDB execution of parallel queries work fine** but I have no idea about more than one database works together into a single application.

So, I hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.